# Printing page automatically opens up on iframe loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have a page containing 3 iFrames. My problem is when I load the page on the browser  the print page automatically opens up for 3 times(1 per iFrame) 
How to prevent this using javascript or jQuery?

```
<iframe src="http://uat3.zawya.com/images/iep/cms/docs/halal/aDOC20150909081714_ver-v1.pdf" width="100%" id="english-pdf-viewer" class="pdf-viewer" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"><p>It appears your web browser doesn't support iframes.</p></iframe>
```

I have this code in page is this cause the issue?

```
$('.pdf-versions').each(function(){
    $(this).on('click', function(){
        $('#' + $(this).attr('name') + '-pdf-viewer').attr('src',$(this).attr('document'));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using iteration loop? Because it not supposed to show it more than once upon onclick method. Provide more of your snippet code.

Comment: Yes it is setting up in the for loop in jsp

Comment: I removed the iteration now just one one iframe it sis till showing the print page on lad, its happening in chrome only

Comment: You mean it's solved now but in Chrome 1 iFrame out of the 3 is coming out?

Comment: nope this behavior only in chrome.. in ff it is fine

Comment: Not certain sure but try to clear the cache memory, few codes only it comes compatible with single browser (unless if it was IE).

Comment: Thanks the issue was due to the pdf file got some issues. I have uploaded a new one and its working